# Issues to compile pex and moles in test project with .net 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, c#-4.0, moles, pex

Tooling: VS 2010, C# 4.0, Test Project, Pex and Moles

I am facing the following issue when compiling a test project that´s using moles.
The main scenario is that

- when I compile the project references in .net 3.5 it works fine
- When I compile the project references in .net 4.0 it throws the exception below

"The type or namespace name 'xxxxx' does not exist in the namespace 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\xxxx.csproj]    C:\xxx\m.g.cs   17275   93  XXXX.Test"

More detais: The dll that´s causing the root problem is in .net 2.0 but I can not compile it in 4.0 cause I don´t have control over it.

Please if anyone has had this problem in the past help me!!